# Does this design induce a voltage in coil? Simple generator

Tags: generator

Will this concept generate an electric current in coil circuit when wheel is rotating? If yes, how much is it effective if there will be many of these coil around wheel?

[image]

Comment: You may have invented the [magneto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto). Hop into a time machine and patent it. Oh - wait ...

Comment: Current will only flow when there is a load.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your drawings right, this is just a permanent-magnet AC generator, with a particularly inefficient layout of magnets and windings. So, yes, but you've not really invented anything new, sorry to say.

Comment: I didnt expect to find something new, I am just curious if generating of electricity can be made with such a simple construction. Regarding to efficiency in my question it was mean if generators from market gives 20W power, is possible to reach 10W with this design at the same volume? (the permanent magnets can be put more often).

Comment: @MichalPodmanický No, I doubt you'll get very much power at all out of this. Enough to light an LED, not enough to light a lightbulb.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look particularly effective.

1: soft iron has eddy current losses, use laminated silicon steel instead.

2: the pole pieces and magnets are not well shaped,  commercial generators use poles and magnets that are shaped to fill space better so that they can be more compact.

Ultimately how well it works depends on how well you build it.